# Reply to reply using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Graph API in my project.
If i want to create user reply to top-level comment, I use this request to fb api:

```
POST /{parent_comment_id}/comments?message={message}
```

and everything is ok.

But when i tried reply to another reply, I've got this error

```
code: 1705, message: (#1705) There was an error posting to this wall [HTTP 400]
```

How i should send my request to fb if I want to reply to another reply?

Comment: Hello, how did you solved the problem. I have the exactly the same problem. I can reply a comment however when I reply to a reply (probably the problem is to tag the user), I am getting exactly the same error. @skowl

Comment: @waterkinq you can reply to the parent comment and mention child's author in the comment body: `"@[USER_ID:USER_NAME]"`. It works for me.